# Real time web crawling using Jsoup

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I have this web page `https://rrtp.comed.com/pricing-table-today/` and from that I need to get the information about Time (Hour Ending) and Day-Ahead Hourly Price column alone. I tried with the following code,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://rrtp.comed.com/pricing-table-today/").get();

for (Element table : doc.select("table.prices three-col")) {
    for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
        Elements tds = row.select("td");

        if (tds.size() > 2) {
           System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + ":" + tds.get(1).text());
        }
    }
}
```

but unfortunately I am unable to get the data I need.

Is there something wrong in the code..? or This page can't be crawled...?

Need some help

Comment: You should probably hit `https://rrtp.comed.com/rrtp/ServletFeed?type=pricingtabledual&date=20150717` (note there's desired date at the end of link). Why? Look at the source of the page (not in element inspector, but i.e. hitting ctrl+u or `view source`). This data is dynamically loaded.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer,                        
 
But i dont know how we can get the data alone, not with the html. i.e I need to crawl Time and price. When I change the url, the output shows the html page as shown below,
`
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  12:00 

  <small>AM</small>2.4¢-0.9¢1:00 

  <small>AM</small>2.2¢-0.5¢2:00 ....
  </body>
</html>
 
but , I need the data to be like

12:00 AM  : 2.4¢

1:00 AM  : 2.2¢........
`
Thank you...!...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comment:

You should hit `https://rrtp.comed.com/rrtp/ServletFeed?type=pricingtabledual&date=20150717` because it's source from which data is loaded on the page you have pointed to.

Data under this link is not a valid html document (and this is why it's not working for you), but you can easily make it "quite" right.

All you have to do is first get the response and add `<table>..</table>` tags around it, then it's enough to parse it as html document.

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://rrtp.comed.com/rrtp/ServletFeed?type=pricingtabledual&date=20150717").execute();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<table>" + response.body() + "</table>");

for (Element element : doc.select("tr")) {
    System.out.println(element.html());
}
```